# Preview of component failing with message 'Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.Evaluator.expressionContext2' not found

Tags: cme, 2013

We are facing a weird behavior when previewing any of the components since yesterday. It is showing a dialog with message 
 
'Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.Evaluator.expressionContext2' not found 
 
when preview of component takes place in Tridion CME. No updates are being installed on the CME server in a recent past. When we ran the component against the component template in template builder, it is showing the desired output properly.

Have you ever come across above issue? If so, could you please suggest how we can get rid of above issue.

Comment: Maybe you could remove the TBBs individually and try to narrow down which TBB throws the error first.